# UIDatePicker not responding to setDate

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I have an app that offers you the option of getting a daily reminder to complete a task. To test it with my beta users on TestFlight, I set up a dummy `UIViewController` and put a switch in it to turn reminders on and off and a `UIDatePicker` (time mode only) in order to set the time. When you first load the view, it reads the existing `UILocalNotification` and displays the current set time on the `UIDatePicker`. You can enable/disable and change the notification time. Works like a charm.

But now I'm finished testing it with my `TestFlight` users and I'm moving the functionality to a new screen. So I rebuilt the entire thing from the ground up, except that I copied and pasted the code from the old testing `View Controller` to the new one. So they are absolutely identical - almost.

The only difference is that the new one has been placed inside of a `UITableViewCell` instead of a `UIViewController` all by itself - this way it matches nicely with the rest of the app's settings.

In the new location, it properly sets the switch state based on whether or not the user has reminders enabled and I am able to use it to enable/disable them. I am also able to change the reminder time to a new time. Works like a charm. However, when I load the new location, the `UIDatePicker` shows the *current* time instead of the time that has been predetermined in the `UILocalNotification`. I am at a total loss to explain it. As I said, the code has been copied and pasted from the old location to the new. The old still works. The new doesn't. Below is the code in question.

I can only assume that it has something to do with being inside of a `UITableViewCell`, since that's the only difference but I cannot fathom why in the world that would matter.

Edit: I have been searching high and low for a solution to this but haven't found any. It seems that using setDate is simply having no effect. I have printed all of my variables to see what they return and everything is correct. It's almost like there's something preventing the `UIDatePicker` from responding to setDate. I can't find any other article anywhere that addresses this. I'm really hoping someone out there has encountered this before.

Thanks for any help!!

```
    if let notificationArray = UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications {

        if notificationArray.count != 0 {

            let oneNotification = notificationArray[0]

            oneNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()

            let savedDate = oneNotification.fireDate

            let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
            let components = NSDateComponents()
            components.hour = calendar.component(.Hour, fromDate: savedDate!)
            components.minute = calendar.component(.Minute, fromDate: savedDate!)

            timePicker.setDate(calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!, animated: false)


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

So I seem to have solved this on my own but not in the way I expected. I was creating the `UIDatePicker` in a `UITableViewCell` in an XIB using the interface designer. On whim and a wonder, I resorted to deleting that and creating it programmatically. It works perfectly!!

The only change I've made to it at all is what I've said above - all other code remained the same, I just connected the programmatically created `UIDatePicker` to the same methods and actions that were left behind by the deleted one.

For the record, I also recreated, in the interface designer, another `UIDatePicker` inside of a `UIViewController` and again copied and pasted the code. It worked fine also. This really does seem to have something to do with it being placed inside of a `UITableViewCell`... Weird.

I'm wondering if this could be a bug? In any case, if you're having the same problem, try that.

Comment: Still a problem three years later.  I am equally perplexed.